# What is wrong with my sentence 我的同屋睡觉时候想开屋门一点点?

Tags: grammar, writing-critique

I wrote this sentence:

> 我的同屋睡觉时候想开屋门一点点.
>   <sub>Wǒ de tóngwū shuìjiào shíhòu xiǎng kāi wūmén yīdiǎndiǎn.</sub>

It was meant to mean "when my roommate sleeps, they like to open the door a little". Our teacher 张老师 made these corrections:

[image: 我的同屋睡觉时候想开屋门一点点]

So she corrected it to:

> 我的[同屋](http://dict.cn/%E5%90%8C%E5%B1%8B)[睡觉](http://dict.cn/%E7%9D%A1%E8%A7%89)**的**[时候](http://dict.cn/%E6%97%B6%E5%80%99)想开**一点点**[屋](http://dict.cn/%E5%B1%8B)门.
>   <sub>Wǒ de tóngwū shuì jué de shíhòu xiǎng kāi yīdiǎndiǎn wūmén.</sub>

I'm not clear as to why.  Judging from Baidu searches for related grammar constructs ([睡觉时候](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E7%9D%A1%E8%A7%89%E6%97%B6%E5%80%99) and [说汉语一点](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E8%AF%B4%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E4%B8%80%E7%82%B9)), what I wrote is plain wrong, but I don't understand why.  It looks important, so...

**Question**: What is wrong with my sentence?

Comment: You can also say我的同屋睡觉时想开一点点屋门。See, Chinese could be very tricky. If u are using 时候,you need to add 的 at front, if you get rid of 候, then 的 shall disappear too. I’m not an expert, so good luck.

Comment: 睡觉的时候 or 睡觉时 are right, but 睡觉时候 is irregular. You may speak 同屋的人 but not 同屋, it is not an adjective. 同事, 同学 vs 朋友, 校友, 舍友.

Comment: That was 2 years 7 months ago. Now, 5 answers later, would you say 我想吃白饭一点点, (I want to eat rice a little bit), or 我想吃一点点白饭? (I want to eat a little bit of rice) ? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since  睡觉 (to sleep) is a verb that doesn't take object,

时候 (time) as a noun cannot follow 睡觉 directly. To resolve the conflict, we  have to add 的 after 睡觉 to make it an adjectival phrase '睡觉的' as in "睡觉的时候" (sleeping time) -- That would then be grammatically correct

In English, the **object** is usually placed **before**  the adverbial phrase -- as in   "open the **door** a little bit"

But in Chinese, the **object** is usually placed **after** the adverbial phrase -- as in "开一点点**屋门**" ( the object '屋门' follows the adverbial phrase '一点点' )

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is still not Chinese i have to say.
Here is somthime interesting.

开 is the verb. 屋门 is the object (noun). So a genuine Chinese is:
我的同屋睡觉的时候，想把屋门开一点点。
Here 把 similiars  to ‘to’ in English.

开屋门 together is an imperative  or a command

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is 一点 here modifies the verb 开， not 开门. So, you have to pull it closer to 开. It's not an big issue with that additional 的 before 时候.

Roommate can be interpreted as 室友，which is more common than 同屋.

a little can be translated to 一点 or 一点点. 一点点 sounds a bit cutie sometimes.

So, the whole sentence can be translated to: 我（的）室友睡觉(的)时候，喜欢开一点（屋）门.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "同屋" with "室友" roommate 
Replace "想开屋门一点点" with "想让屋门开着一点点", want to leave the door open a bit

Answer (score 0):

同居 is not an ideal way to express roommates. 室友 should be a better word.
想把屋门打开一点点 makes sense to me.
‘我的室友睡觉的时候会把屋门打开一点点‘ would be the way I say it.
'My roommate will leave the door open a little when he/she goes to the bed.'